# A new field doesn't show on the page

Tags: 7, entities

I recovered a site from a backup which had run on Drupal 7.7. I upgraded it to Drupal 7.80 on another instance. Now, we need to add new fields to content types and add new nodes. I added a field as an administrator.  I can't see the added field on either the old site or the new one.

What I have done so far:

- I checked the node is published
- I checked the permissions
- I flushed the cache
- I verified the field data is stored in the database

I don't think it's the cache, as I am able to modify the existing field content.
I can delete the pre-existing fields and restore them; I can remove and re-add the nodes. The field stores the same configuration data than the other fields.
The cache_field table data column for the content type with the new field does have the field in the JSON.
When I check on the page in a dev console, there's no trace of the field. It must be skipped during PHP processing of the content type.

What am I missing?

Anyone please?  Perhaps you could tell me which .inc files are responsible for showing the content type.  I can read into the code and debug then.

Thank you!

Comment: This is probably as simple as the field display setting being hidden on the node display or the field not being rendered in the theme template(s).

Comment: @Kevin you are right I just found that the template just needed that new field after debugging the hell out of Drupal.  Thank you!